# WPF MVVM TabControl to display my Views/ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a collection of ViewModels which items Im trying to display in the Main View using this:

```
    public ObservableCollection<object> PlateViewModelItemsSource
    {
        get { return _plateViewModelItemsSource; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._plateViewModelItemsSource, value); }
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlateViewModelItemsSource}"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PlateViewModel}">
                <v:PlateView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    </TabControl>
```

I dont understand whats wrong with this XAML - I get a TabControl, which shows PlateViews both in TabItem and its TabHeader. Tried to modify TabHeader style - changes nothing at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got it :) - I had this in Window.Resources: 
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PlateViewModel}">
<v:PlateView/>
</DataTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I have overlooked, that I had same datatemplate defined in Window.Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PlateViewModel}">
        <v:PlateView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```